# Spring data using Neo4j and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, cross-domain, neo4j, spring-data

I am just about to go crazy,I just spent many hours to try work with spring-data for **Neo4J**,working with spring-data for **MongoDB** was a walk in the park compared to that.

***My goals:*** 
 1) Working with spring-data to manage two data-stores Mongo,Neo4j.
(correct me if I am wrong but there is no spring-data cross data store support for these two, which mean I will use different domain entities for each store)
2) Working with Neo4J embedded graph.
3) Will have the ability to monitor the graph with some client like the web admin.

So I started with [Good Relationship spring-data example](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/)
, where using :

```
       POM
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>
       XML
       <neo4j:config storeDirectory="data/graph.db"/>
```

So my first question is how can I monitor the graph In that configuration, in which client?
So I read more and I got to [Neo4j Web Admin for embedded graph configuration](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/2012/05/23/enabling-neo4j-web-admin-tool-on-the-embedded-server-using-spring-data/)

I followed every step tried it and boom!

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.haze.server.repository.mongo.ProfileRepository com.haze.server.services.ProfileServices.profileRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'profileRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.core.RepositoryMetadata.getDomainClass()Ljava/lang/Class;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
... 39 more
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'profileRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.core.RepositoryMetadata.getDomainClass()Ljava/lang/Class;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1442)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:876)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:818)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:735)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
... 41 more
  Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.core.RepositoryMetadata.getDomainClass()Ljava/lang/Class;
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:84)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:137)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:125)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:41)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
... 49 more
```

Make long story short the only version configuration I find to get spring context to load is

```
      <spring.data.mongo.version>1.0.4.RELEASE</spring.data.mongo.version>
   <neo4j.version>1.6</neo4j.version>
   <spring-data-neo4j.version>2.0.1.RELEASE</spring-data-neo4j.version>
```

If I am adding the below dependency like specify in the article it crashed.

```
 <spring-data-commons-core.version>1.3.0.RELEASE</spring-data-commons-core.version>
```

Ok so I got it working after many hours with the neo4j embedded graph and the server wrapper in order to monitor the graph from the web admin with mongo as my primary datastore.

Kind of happy but sad cause using old version for the neo4j server wrapper (1.6 cause that is the only thing which worked) I was motivated to start working with the graph via spring-data.

So I got the most basic node entity:

```
@NodeEntity
public class ProfileNode {
@GraphId
private Long id;
@Indexed(unique = true)
private String pid = null;
}
```

Tried some basic operations:

```
                     // save node - OK
        ProfileNode node = new ProfileNode();
        node.setPid("44ed79b3ea8a99117aa601b16e916ddr");
        ProfileNode profile = graphRepo.save(node);

        // return NULL
        node = graphRepo.findByPropertyValue("pid",
                "44ed79b3ea8a99117aa601b16e916ddr");
        // throwing exception -    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:read only index                 
        graphRepo.delete(profile);
```

Basically almost every basic operation I tried didn't worked for me.

I don't know if the problems occur because of my mishmash configurations or that I am doing something wrong In my code, can someone please help me configure my application or let me know why the most basic operation via spring data doesn't work for me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update to 2.1.RC4 as Lasse said.

Regarding using the embedded server with SDN, it is described in the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-graph/snapshot-site/reference/html/#d5e1706).

What does your repository look like?

Answer (score 0):

You really should upgrade to SDN 2.1.RC4, it will be out as GA in a metter of weeks.

Secondly, here is some code to get you started: https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-neo4j/blob/master/spring-data-neo4j/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/repository/DerivedFinderTests.java - you can add a test for findByPropertyValue if you are not keen on derived finders, but at least this works out of the box using just that single file, i.e. you can eliminate Spring config as a source of errors.

For cross-store: I see little point in cross-store with MongoDB, to me cross-store is all about transactions across multiple data sources. With MongoDB + Neo, I'd just build different repositories and on the application level do just enough to use them concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have `spring-data-mongodb-1.1.0.RC1` and `spring-data-neo4j-2.1.0.RC4`. Both of those have the same `spring-data-commons-core` dependency.

[spring-data with neo4j + mongo version conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698204/spring-data-with-neo4j-mongo-version-conflicts)