# spring-data with neo4j + mongo version conflicts

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-mongodb

In my spring application I am working with **Neo4j** DB via **spring-data** project.
I want to add **mongo** db as another data store to my application.
It seems that there some conflictions while trying to work with these two data stores together.

**my pom - only the relevant dependencies:**

```
    <spring.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.data.mongo.version>1.0.4.RELEASE</spring.data.mongo.version>
    <neo4j.version>1.8.RC1</neo4j.version>
    <spring-data-neo4j.version>2.1.0.RC4</spring-data-neo4j.version>
    <spring-data-commons.version>1.4.0.RC1</spring-data-commons.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.6.0</slf4j.version>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.data.mongo.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-neo4j.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RC1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        <classifier>static-web</classifier>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

**I am getting the following exception while trying to load spring application context:**

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at    org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
at   org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [mongo-config.xml]
 Offending resource: class path resource [core-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [mongo-config.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.MongoNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/config/AbstractRepositoryConfigDefinitionParser
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:271)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:196)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:181)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:205)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:100)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(DelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:228)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
... 24 more
  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [mongo-config.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.MongoNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/config/AbstractRepositoryConfigDefinitionParser
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:255)
... 42 more
  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.MongoNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/config/AbstractRepositoryConfigDefinitionParser
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:139)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1414)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1409)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
... 45 more
  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:    org/springframework/data/repository/config/AbstractRepositoryConfigDefinitionParser
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.MongoNamespaceHandler.init(MongoNamespaceHandler.java:35)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:130)
... 52 more
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:      org.springframework.data.repository.config.AbstractRepositoryConfigDefinitionParser
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 66 more
```

I am guessing there are versions conflict so i tried to change some versions but without any luck, can any one please help to set this up..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy fix, you don't have the latest version of Spring-Data-MongoDB. Change it to `1.1.0.RC1`. 1.0.4 depends on an older version of `spring-data-commons-core`.

The proof is in the poms:

[Spring-Data-MongoDB 1.1.0.RC1 pom](http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/org/springframework/data/spring-data-mongodb-parent/1.1.0.RC1/spring-data-mongodb-parent-1.1.0.RC1.pom)

[Spring-Data-Neo4j 2.1.0.RC4 pom](http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/org/springframework/data/spring-data-neo4j-parent/2.1.0.RC4/spring-data-neo4j-parent-2.1.0.RC4.pom)